# List all Functions in an Excel Object browser Addin

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins

I'm looking to dump all functions and their paramaters to a text file. We have no documentation and are looking to at least see what functions are available. Can this be done in VBA? I do not have access to the source code for these libraries only the object browser

[image]

Comment: https://www.mztools.com/v8/features.aspx#GetDocumentation

Comment: An additional note, I didn't write any of the libraries nor have access to them. Only can see the methods in the object browser

Comment: Maybe you could provide a little more information - for example what kind of add-in is it?  It looks like an xla/xlam but maybe that's not all it is?

Comment: Hi Tim, it's an Excel addin (xla). I was of the thinking if the object browser can load all the functions and methods then there must be a way to dump these.

Comment: There is - you can either write it yourself using one of the available references like http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx or use an existing tool like the one I linked.

Comment: Does the .xla add-in use a .dll keeping some functions, only called by it? Do you see the add-in in discussion in VBE Project Explorer? If yes, when you try to expand the VBProject, does the window asking the password appear? Or 'The project is unviewable' message?

Comment: Yes some do require a password and others do not.